# Why Seams are visible at a distance?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

Yes the Seam placement is rather questionable, but anyways... Whats up with this? :P

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[Edit in response to Rix Yarbrough]

Version 2.79b

[image: So it seems]

Mesh is consistent if that is what you are asking for.

[Edit]

Welp, I minimized the damage this problem does by redoing the UV n Texture Tho it still stands.
[image]

Hmhmhm, i wonder if it would disappear if the adjacent faces to the seam were to be flat. Ill test that out. :p
(a longshot of an idea that i got form Normal map err... seamlisity :p )

[Edit]

Yeah never mind that, maybe if the UV island edges were to be perfectly horizontal andor vertical.

Comment: A few questions: What version of Blender? Does this appear when rendered? Are these faces attached directly?